# Webcam hack while laptop is offline

Tags: network, malware, attacks, exploit, hardware

Well, basically the subject says for it self.

Is it actually possible to hack the webcam of a PC that is turned off?

We're not talking about an infected machine. For example, by remotely turning on the PC.

Answer (score 2):

If by offline, you mean the PC is turned-off then obviously not.

If you mean not connected to the Internet, then possibly. Since you could still have a local network infection or one via USB or via a document opened.

But you've specified that the machine is "not infected". So that only leaves remote control via a non-infection route. If we further assume Windows, that leaves you with someone running a script remotely using a valid but unapproved account. Clearly that would need either a network or someone with physical access logging in without your permission.

Take your pick.

---

OK, so if the computer itself is turned off. It is certainly possible to remotely start a computer if it has been configured for it (WOL = Wake On LAN). This is normally disabled for obvious reasons.

If the attacker also has access to your account or a system account then they can remotely run scripts on Windows using PowerShell.

Much of what you can do locally with PowerShell can be run by a remote "administrator" with the right level of access. See [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2b162a63-cf2b-46df-8ec2-45378599fac9) as an example of capturing an image using PowerShell. It is then trivial in PowerShell to send that image, maybe via a webpage or via your own email application.

This is a pretty unlikely scenario in most cases. It is far more likely that the camera is accessed via malware on the PC.

However, it is trivially easy to make sure you are never spied on. Just put a flap of paper over the camera, secured with some tape across the top edge. When you want to use it, fold the paper up. You can get plastic sliders that are a little more sophisticated but basically, they do the same job.

Comment: The first one. I actually think the same. But, I thought maybe I don't know something. Maybe there is some way, like turning on the machine remotely. Because I've watched the Snowden movie and there was a scene where the computer was off(seems so, but perhaps the screen was just turned off - but I doubt about this 'cause of circumstances), and the guy thought The Big Bro may spy on him. Thanks for your answer

Comment: See my update .

Comment: @Julian why would there be any worry of "local network infection" if he isn't connected to the internet, presumably also the network?  There is also turning off network discovery, as well as firewall/protection software blocking connections from LAN connectivity.

Comment: @XaolingBao, what I was thinking was that the PC itself might be blocked from the Internet but there might be other devices on the network that did, if only occasionally and therefore other machines that might already be infected. My byzantine thought processes in action ;-)